# multiple rows with one INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, insert

I am developing an administration panel for my site locally. I would need to insert multiple rows with a single INSERT INTO query.
Initially I transform the string saved with commas into an array and then I try with a foreach loop to insert but it doesn't work ...

```
$aa = explode(',', $data['recipe_ingredient']); 
<!-- Result Array ( [0] => one element [1] => second element [2] => third element )  -->
       foreach($aa as $entry) {
          $this->db->query('INSERT INTO recipes_ingredient (recipe_id, recipe_ingredient_name)
                            VALUES (:last_id, :name)'); <-- :name contain "n" result
       
            $this->db->bind(':last_id', $this->db->lastId());
            $this->db->bind(':name', $entry);
             
                
            if($this->db->execute()) {
               return true;
            } else {
               return false;
            }
       }
```

Anyone have any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Some explanation of *but it doesn't work* would help.

Comment: Hi Nigel, right. It practically doesn't put me multiple lines inside the Mysql.
I have a table with some values. recipe ingredient [] has a series of "n" values ​​and for each value I would like to save one line (if recipe_ingredient [] has 6 values, I would like to save 6 lines).
I hope I have explained ...

Comment: You are returning on foreach, that's mean that you are braking the execution

Comment: this may be interesting to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426681/insert-array-of-values-into-columns-of-the-table-in-sql-server/44426787, because you can add an entire array in to a SQL table

Comment: in your opinion which would be the best method?

Comment: Hi @ErnestoAlfonso, i see the link but the problem is that not dinamically. in my query i have one value equal for all the query inserted ":last_id" and other value ":name" is dinamically value.

Comment: You can do only one dynamic value with the array an remove que loop, still you are returning on a loop, this break the entire execution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617144/break-vs-continue-vs-return

Comment: Thanks @ErnestoAlfonso, another questions. Can i make a loop of VALUES? To insert more values ​​we use the form VALUES ('1', '2'), ('1', '2') and I would need just this but dynamically. EX.. VALUES ('last_id', 'name1'), ('last_id', 'name2'), etc ...

Comment: I see, in this case you are adding the latest Id inserted, you can keep do this like you are doing now, but I insist you need to remove the return